# LogiXML Security - Basic Authentication

Tags: security, authentication, iis

I'm pretty new to the forums and new to programming in general.  My question regarding LogiXML is the following:

I have a LogiXML website which requires Basic Authentication (IIS) for them to log in.  I want LogiXML to use this username and password combination to authenticate the user so that they may save dashboards, charts, etc (their own @Username.xml file with everything saved).  I have added the security component to the settings tab in LogiXML, set the Authentication Source to "AuthSession" and Security Enabled to "True" but I get the following error:

"The Session variable "rdUserName" must be set when AuthenticationSource="AuthSession""

I appreciate any help I can get on the matter, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Basic Auth from within IIS to pass user credentials to the application, then you'll want to use the Security option for "AuthNT" instead of "AuthSession".   "AuthNT" uses the operating system's security to get the Username -- in this case, your Basic authentication setting. You'll also need to make sure that anonymous access for the web site in IIS is disabled.

For more details on setting up the various types of security in LogiXML you might want to have a look at this article on the Logi DevNet on 
Security Scenarios :
http://devnet.logixml.com/rdPage.aspx?rdReport=Article&dnDocID=1186

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  That certainly takes care of the problem. However, fix something and something else breaks! Whenever I try to open a particular dashboard, I get this message:

Could not find a part of the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Dashboard2\SavedDashboards\username.xml'.

Where username is of course my username.  I have given write permission to users and what not, but the problem still surfaces.  Any ideas would be appreciated! Thank you! :)

Comment: Also, isn't AuthNT only used when Integrated Windows Authentication is enabled? (Which is not the same as Basic Authentication).

Comment: AuthNT can work as long as the authentication credential is being passed.  So, Integrated Windows Auth would pass it, automatically -- as will Basic Authentication.   

The dashboard error is likely due to an invalid path -- is the file there ?   Or folder permissions.  You may need to explicitly add users to read-write (or full control) over this directory.  Also, if the file was created prior to changing permission on the folder, you might want to remove the file and have the engine automatically add it back.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I just tested it locally and everything seems to work just fine! There was definitely a permissions error which is now fixed.  Thanks for your help! I will let you know how it works :)